# PHP Random Display of Variables

Tags: php

I have a variable called

```
  $core
```

I also have 3 other variables called

```
 $one, $two, $three
```

I need to (many times) display a random combination of these where $core is always included and 1 of the 3 other variables are included once either before or after:

eg:

```
 $two $core
 $core $one
 $three $core
 $core $two
```

I'm unsure how to get this randomness working with PHP?
A push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

thx

Comment: Do they have to be named that? You could create a function that returns an array containing those values in a random order, except for the $core value being index 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the three variables in an array. Then call `rand()` between 0 and 1 to determine whether an array value or `$core` should be printed first. At the same time, call a random value from the array

```
// Array of the three vars
$arr = ($one, $two, $three);
// If 0 is chosen, print an array value then $core. 
// Otherwise print $core than an array value
echo rand(0, 1) == 0 ? $arr[rand(0,2)] . " " . $core : $core . " " . $arr[rand(0,2)];
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use individual variables. Use an array:

```
$vals = array($one, $two, $three);
```

build a temporary array:

```
$new = array($core, $vals[array_rand($vals, 1)]);
```

and then shuffle it:

```
shuffle($new);
```

Comment: This wont randomize whether $core comes before or after the value printed. *edit* oh wait, misread

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps store all 4 values in an array. Randomly select an item. Remove it. If the value isn't `$core`, randomly select again from the shorter array.