# PHP Random Variable

Tags: php

Using an answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705064/php-random-display-of-variables).  I am trying to randomly select a URL found for a PHP variable called $url.

Here is the current code:

```
$url1 = "https://www.domain1.com/tds/parser.php?station=".$_GET['id'];
$url2 = "https://www.domain2.com/tds/parser.php?station=".$_GET['id'];

$vals = array($url1,$url2);

$url = array($vals[array_rand($vals, 1)]);

echo $url;
```

My echo statement returns just the words 'array' instead of the actual url randomly selected?

Comment: `var_dump( $url );` will reveal your issue.

Comment: You didn't select a URL, you just shuffled the array. Now you can use `echo $url[0]`

Comment: `$url = array($vals[array_rand($vals, 1)]);` is confusing and probably unnecessary. Just `shuffle($vals);` and `echo $vals[0];`

Comment: your shuffle is useless because at this point, your array.length === 1

Comment: I don't want to display the url with an echo, I want to make that variable available for later in the program after it's randomly shuffled.

Comment: okie dokie, so use an assignment operator instead of `echo`

Comment: `$url =$vals[array_rand($vals, 1)];` ?

Comment: `$url = $vals[rand(0, (count($vals) - 1))];` or use the shuffle and `$vals[0];` that @MonkeyZeus mentioned

Comment: $url = array($vals[array_rand($vals, 1)]);

$url will contain an array. If you echo it, it will display Array and a Notice: Array to string conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:
`$url = array($vals[array_rand($vals, 1)]);`

> This will assign an array to the variable `$url`

Change it to `$url = $vals[array_rand($vals, 1)];`

```
<?php

$vals = array(
    "https://www.domain1.com/tds/parser.php?station=".$_GET['id'],
    "https://www.domain2.com/tds/parser.php?station=".$_GET['id']
);

$url = $vals[array_rand($vals, 1)];

echo $url;
```